# XMPP chat and Notification together?

Tags: xmpp

I want to integrate my web application with chat and notification service and the foremost and the best, i understand is XMPP. After going through the nitty gritties, though i understood most of it but I got stuck here i.e. how will i run a Chat and notification service together.

One option is to have run different connections of Strophe, long polling with different accounts one for chat and other for notifications.

Other one is to have both notifications and chat on the same accounts but now the problem if the user signs out from chat he wont be able to receive notifications.

The first option does not seem feasible to me, but is there a way the later one could work?

Answer (score 0):

Use one connection, to your "chat" service.  Run your notification service as a *component* on your chat server, or run a separate server and federate them together.  The client will be able to contact the notification service (and vice-versa) via the naming scheme in the Jabber ID's (JIDs) that you pick.  Make sure you pick a different domain name for the user accounts on the chat side than for the notification service.